Two distinct homomorphisms that agree on a subgroup.
I am stuck on the following problem from these notes (problem 2.23(b)).

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H ⊂ G$ be a subgroup with $H \not = G$. Construct a group $K$ and two group homomorphisms $G$ to $K$ that agree on $H$ but not on all of $G$.

So far I've got nothing concrete. I did look at $N_G(H)$. I was thinking if two different element induce the same automorphism on $H$ i could maybe try inner automorphisms from them. And also other trivial cases like if the centralizer of $H$ has nontrivial elements etc. This has been my thought process so far.
I would appreciate any hints or help towards the solution.
Thank you

Can $H$ be trivial?

Yes, but i believe we are already given an H

Do you know about the amalgamated free product construction? (AKA the pushout in the category of groups)

Ah no, I am afraid not, if you take a look at the notes that I've linked then these are in the group actions section and I don't think the author meant that to be used

You can do this with $K=S_{|G|}$; think about the regular representation, and how you might reorder the points of $G$ so that $H$ still acts the same.

I'm sorry but I don't seem to understand the part: "reorder points of G so that H acts the same", do we mean an automorphism of G?

Or I think $K = (G / H) \times (G / H)$ can work.

IMO It's hard to give hints without giving away the full solution. By "reorder" I meant permuting $G$ (as a set!) via an inner automorphism of $S_G$. In order to ignore an annoying corner case, it's good to assume $H$ is non-normal in $G$; when $H\lhd G$ this is very easy.

I just looked at the notes you linked; part (a) gives a version of what I've been hinting at. Have you done that part already?

The existence of such a construction is equivalent to the fact that epimorphisms in the category of groups are surjective.

Yeah I had done part (a) I did consider cosets of H for part (b) but didn't see a way to make the group actions into a homomorphism

The construction here solves the problem. Though the claimed property is stronger than "every epimorphism is surjective", the proof establishes the stronger claim (that every subgroup is an equalizer subgroup).

I think part (a) of the exercise you linked gives an easy path to the solution.

 Let $X$ be a set $G$ acts on transitively, and let $x_0\in X$, with $H\le G$ the stabilizer of $x_0$. If $\hat{X}\cong_G X$ but is disjoint from $X$, we can form $Y=X\sqcup\hat{X}$. There is a permutation $\pi$ of $Y$, swapping $x_0$ and $\hat{x}_0$, but fixing all other points. This permutation commutes with the action of $H$, but not of $G$.

Here's how to use it to solve part (b):

 Let $X=G/H$ be the cosets of $H$ in $G$. As above, we get a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_Y$. The element $\pi\in S_Y$ centralizes $\phi(H)$, but not $\phi(G)$. Thus if $\sigma$ is the inner automorphism that is conjugation by $\pi$, then $\sigma\phi:G\rightarrow S_Y$ is another homomorphism which agrees with $\phi$ on $H$, but not on $G$.

I had hinted at a similar way to solve this exercise in the comments. Let $\rho:G\rightarrow S_G$ be the regular representation. If $T$ is a transversal for $H$ in $G$, then any permutation $\tau\in S_T$ induces a permutation $\pi_\tau$ in $S_G$, by sending $th\mapsto \tau(t)h$. This permutation will fix each coset of $H$, and hence preserve the action of $H$ in the regular representation. To finish the problem, we need some $g\in G\setminus H$ that will act differently before/after applying $\pi_\tau$. This is always possible when $H$ is not normal in $G$, because then there exists $x\in G\setminus H$ and $y\in H$ such that $x^{-1}yx\not\in H$. Let $T$ be a transversal with $\{1,x\}\subset T$, and let $\tau=(1,x)$ be the transposition on $T$. Then for $h\in H$ and $tk\in TH$ we have
\begin{equation}
\pi_\tau\left(\rho(h)(tk)\right) = \pi_\tau(tkh) = \tau(t)kh = \rho(h)\left(\pi_\tau(tk)\right)
\end{equation}
However, if $yx=t_0h_0$, then
\begin{equation}
\pi_\tau\left(\rho(x)(y)\right) = \pi_\tau(yx)=\pi_\tau(t_0h_0)=\tau(t_0)h_0
\end{equation}
Meanwhile,
\begin{equation}
\rho(x)\left(\pi_\tau(y)\right) = \rho(x)(xy) = x(yx) = xt_0h_0
\end{equation}
For these to be equal, we must have $xt_0=\tau(t_0)$. Since $t_0\not\in\{1,x\}$, this is impossible.

After reading this I guess it does seem a bit more evident, although at the time I got the hint in the comments i actually had not much idea what to do with it.
